# Remove lines from CSV file if the second column is in a word list

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, ruby

I have found a long list of free email providers that I want to remove from my email lists - https://gist.github.com/tbrianjones/5992856

Below are two commands I currently use that do the same job for a handful or single domain entries however how can I convert these to import the words from another file? `remove.txt` for example rather than adding all of them manually.

```
ruby -rcsv -i -ne 'row = CSV::parse_line($_); puts $_ unless row[2] =~ /gmail|hotmail|qq.com|yahoo|live.com|comcast.com|icloud.com|aol.co/i' All.txt

sed -i '/^[^,]*,[^,]*hotmail/d' All.txt
```

Below is a line of the data we will be using this on

```
"fox*******","scott@sc***h.com","821 Ke****on Rd","Neenah","Wisconsin","54***6","UNITED STATES"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. create a remover script (AUX) with `print unless m!gmail.com!hotmail.com|...!` (the regular expressio is huge but there is no problem)
2. apply it to `All.txt`

Code:

```
perl -n0E 's/\n/|/g; say "print unless m!\\b($_ç)\\b!\n" ' remove.txt > AUX
perl -n AUX    All.txt > outfile
```

Update1:
  to be case-insensitive add a `i`in the match operator:

```
perl -n0E 's/\n/|/g; say "print unless m!@($_=)\\b!i\n" ' remove.txt > AUX
```

Update2
   to have extra remove domains: create a new file with the
exception list (extra.txt) and:

```
cat remove.txt extra.txt | 
  perl -n0E 's/\n/|/g; say "print unless m!@($_=)\\b!i\n" ' > AUX
perl -n AUX   All.txt > outfile
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. It did it instantly, it is not processing capitals though YAhoO.cOm for example - How can I do that?

Comment: @Teddy291, Please check the update.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to bother you again but I have one more request. If I wanted to remove privacyprotect.org but only "privacy" is in the remove.txt file how would I include that?

Comment: @Tedd291, in that case you could (1) add this new domain to `remove.txt` or (2) create an `extra.txt` and do `cat remove extrar.txt | perl -n0E '.......\n' > AUX`

Comment: The line "privacy" is in the remove.txt or extra.txt yet emails containing domainnameprivacyemail.com for example 92977d4025d75d003b7ce0126d2eecc8@domainnameprivacyemail.com are not being removed.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
{   sed -ne's/./^[^,]*,[^,]*&/p' | 
    grep -vf- ./All.txt 
}   <./remove.txt >./outfile
```

Is what I think you are asking about. I'm not sure how it is relevant to `ruby` or to the line of data you're talking about...

If you want the matches to be case-insensitive then just add the `-i`gnore case option to `grep` like:

```sh
{   sed -ne's/./^[^,]*,[^,]*&/p' | 
    grep -ivf- ./All.txt 
}   <./remove.txt >./outfile
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work if they have capitals in the email (YAhoO.com for example)

Comment: @Teddy291 - Use `grep -ivf-`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any quicker ways of doing this? The file is over 80MB in size and I expect it to be down to 20-30MB after processing, it's been running for 12 hours and has only outputted 1MB. There are 3618 keywords to delete.

Comment: @Teddy291 - Wow. That's pretty awful. Yes. Quicker would be to use multiple `grep`s on a subset of the match against list. Quicker still would be to use `-F`ixed-string matches, but in that case you wouldn't be able to anchor and could only do: `grep . remove.txt | grep -ivFf- All.txt`, but in the latter case you'd drop all occurrences of any match in `remove.txt` no matter where it was made in your string. Safely you might split out your file to only the matchable bits: `sed -ne's/[^@]*@\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' <All.txt |  grep -iFxnf remove.txt | sed 's/:.*/d/' | sed -f- All.txt >out`

Comment: If you did the above in 5-10 passes, say on 5-10 smaller chunks of remove.txt, you could probably finish the deal in 5 minutes or so. The more you can reduce tthe number of matches `grep` has to check against per line the better.

Comment: sed -ne's/[^@]*@\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' <1.txt | grep -iFxnf freeemails.txt | sed 's/:.*/d/' | sed -f- 1.txt > NoFreeEmails-1.txt - That was doing something for 15+ minutes with a 4MB file but it didn't remove anything