# sed multiple entries in one command to remove data

Tags: sed

I am using the following `sed` command to remove emails that contain `hotmail` - Is it possible to check for multiple entries at the same time? Preferably load it from `list.txt` (one entry per line).

```
sed -i '/^[^,]*,[^,]*hotmail/Id' data.txt
```

If I can't load it from a .txt is there a way to do something like `hotmail|gmail|yahoo`

`data.txt` line example:

```
"foxva****omes****","scott@hotmail.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@gmail.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@foo.you","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
```

Comment: Would `grep` be better for this task?

Comment: I have tried with grep but it took far too long, there are several thousand words to process for removal

Comment: @Teddy291 - `sed` will *not* be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` if you can format the file in the form of a `sed` script you can do it automatically. The following should work w/ a GNU `sed`. With a BSD `sed` it will work if you do `-i '' -e` for the second `sed` invocation...

```sh
sed -ne's|[]\*&^.$/[]|\\&|g' \
     -e's|..*|/^@&",/d|p' <./list.txt |
sed -ie'h;s/[^,]*[^@]*//' -f- -eg ./data.txt
```

If you do...

```sh
-e's|..*|/^@&",/Id|p' ...
```

...in the second line a GNU `sed` will `d`elete matches for  any line in *`list.txt`* case insensitively, but it will amount to a syntax error with most any other.

It tries to optimize the matches by removing the first field and everything before the first `@` in the second field at the head of the script it runs for every line, then does the match checks, and, if the line makes it through all of them, `g`ets a copy of the line it saved at the top of the script in `h`old space. In that way `sed` doesn't need to `/^[^,]*,[^,]*.../` for every match. If *`list.txt`* is very long, though, it will not be a fast process regardless. `grep -F` should be preferred in that case *(and probably in this case)*.

---

Both `sed` and `grep` *can* be made to perform better - and in many cases *signifigantly* so - if the charset used is reduced in size. For example, if you are currently in a UTF-8 locale then doing:

```sh
(   export LC_ALL=C
    sed -ne's|[]\*&^.$/[]|\\&|g' \
         -e's|..*|/^@&",/Id|p'   |
    sed -ie'h;s/[^,]*[^@]*//' -f-\
         -eg ./data.txt
)   <./list.txt
```

...can make a world of difference in that rather than having to consider some umpteen-thousand different characters as matches, the regex engine need only consider 128 possibilities. It should not affect the results in any way - each char is a byte in the C locale and all will get due consideration.

`sed -i` is not a reliable switch to use in the best of cases, and should be avoided if at all possible.

---

To do this w/ `grep` *and* `sed -i`:

```sh
(   export LC_ALL=C
    cut -d\" -f4 | cut -d@ -f2    |
    grep -Fixnf ./list.txt        |
    sed -e's|:*\([0-9]*\).*|:\1|p'\
        -e's||\1!{p;n;b\1|p'      \
        -e's||};n|'               |
    sed -nif- -e:n -e'p;n;bn'     \
        ./data.txt
)   <./data.txt
```

That is the quickest way I can imagine it might be done with `sed`'s `-i`. It breaks down like this:

1. `cut | cut`

   - The first two `cut`s reduce your `./data.txt` input lines from/to...

   ```
    "foxva****omes****","scott@hotmail.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
   ```

   ---

   ```
   hotmail.com
   ```
2. `grep`

   - `grep` can then compare that input against each line in its pattern `-f`ile *`list.txt`* using case `-i`nsensitive `-F`ixed string `-x` whole line matches and reporting the line `-n`umber at the head of each line of its output.
3. `sed -e`

   - `sed` strips `grep`'s output to nothing but the line numbers and writes out another `sed` script which looks like *(given hypothetical `grep` matches on lines 10 and 20)*:

   ```
    :10
    10!{p;n;b10
    };n
    :20
    20!{p;n;b20
    };n
   ```
4. `sed -inf-`

   - The last `sed` reads `-`stdin as its script and only ever executes it the one time - it doesn't backtrack and execute the script for every input line as is commonly done w/ `sed` scripts, but rather as it executes its script the first and only time it works its way through input - and it needs only try a single test per input line.
   - Given our previous example, for lines 1-9 `sed` will do:

     - If the current line is `!`not the `10`th, `{`then `p`rint the current line, overwrite the current line with the `n`ext input line, and `b`ranch back to the `:`label named `10`.
   - and for the last series of lines `sed` will `p`rint; then overwrite the current line with the `n`ext, the `b`ranch to the `:n` label until it has consumed all input.

---

That doesn't work if *`./data.txt`* is very large because `sed` gets stuck trying to process a script input file far larger than it can reliably handle. The way around that is to take input in chunks. This *can* be done reliably - even in a pipeline - if you use the right kind of reader. `dd` is that right kind of reader.

I created a test file like this:

```sh
sh -c ' _1=\"foxva****omes****\",\"scott@
        _2='\''","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"'\''
        n=0
        for m do printf "$_1%s$_2\n$_1$((n+=1))not_free.com$_2\n" "$m"
        done
'       $(cat ~/Downloads/list.txt) >/tmp/data.txt
```

...where *`list.txt`* is got [here](https://gist.github.com/tbrianjones/5992856) per your [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216863/52934). It does every other line like...

```
"foxva****omes****","scott@11mail.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@1not_free.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@123.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
"foxva****omes****","scott@2not_free.com","8*** Rd","Ne***ah","Wi***in","54***","*******"
```

I then brought it up to a little over 80mbs like...

```sh
while [ "$(($(wc -c <data.txt)/1024/1024))" -lt 80 ]
do    cat <<IN >./data.txt
$(    cat ./data.txt ./data.txt)
IN
done
ls -hl ./data.txt
wc -l <./data.txt
```

---

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 81M Jul 19 22:22 ./data.txt
925952
```

...and then I did...

```sh
(   trap rm\ data.tmp 0;  export  LC_ALL=C
    <./data.txt dd bs=64k cbs=512 conv=block    |
    while       dd bs=64k cbs=512 conv=unblock  \
                count=24  of=./data.tmp
                [ -s ./data.tmp ]
    do          
    <./data.tmp cut -d\" -f4 |  cut -d@  -f2    |
                grep -Fixnf ./list.txt          |
                sed -e's|:*\([0-9]*\).*|:\1|p'  \
                    -e's||\1!{p;n;b\1|p'        \
                    -e's||};n|'                 |
                sed -nf- -e:n -e'p;n;bn' ./data.tmp
    done        2>/dev/null
)|  wc -l
```

---

```
1293+1 records in
7234+0 records out
474087424 bytes (474 MB) copied, 21.8488 s, 21.7 MB/s
462976
```

You can see right there that the whole process took 22 seconds, and that the output line count is at least correct - 462976 is half of 925952 and the input should have come out halved.

The technique works because `dd`'s reads and writes can be counted upon to the byte - even over a pipe if you know what you're about. And you can even break input out *by line* with the same degree of precision if you can reliably `conv`ert by a maximum line-length `block`-size *(which is 512 here, or `{_POSIX_LINE_MAX}`)*.

The imaginative reader might rightly surmise that the same technique could be applied to an in-stream of any kind - even the live-log kind - with only a slight modification here or there *(namely, to do it safely, the first `dd`'s arguments would need to change from [`bs=` to `obs=`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192114/52934))*. In every case, though, you would need some assurance of the maximum input line size, and, if a line can legitimately end in a <space> character, some additional filter mechanism inserted before the `dd` processes to protect against the trailing <spaces> being stripped with `dd conv=unblock` *(which works by stripping off all trailing blanks for each `cbs`-sized `conv`ersion block and appending a `\n`ewline)*. `tr` and `(un|)expand` spring to my mind as likely candidates for such a filter.

This is not the fastest way to do this - for that you'd want to look to a [`-m`erge `sort`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209441/52934) operation, I expect, but it is pretty quick, and it will work with your data. It does kind of break the `sed -i` thing, though - but I think that will be true no matter which way you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a couple of different ways. For one, `sed` supports multiple expressions in a single run:

```
sed -i -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*hotmail/Id' -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*gmail/Id' -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*yahoo/Id' data.txt
```

You can also do this in a single expression:

```
sed -i -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*\(hotmail\|gmail\|yahoo\)/Id' data.txt
```

Note that the `(`, `)`, and `|`, all need to be escaped.

Comment: The former or the latter?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I edited to correct. I hadn't realized that `|` needed to be escaped. I just tested this with GNU sed version 4.2.2 and it worked properly; but, you're right, without the escapes, it doesn't. Is there still something I'm missing?

Comment: Just a clarification on which `sed`s will actually handle that syntax. And the `-e` isn't strict;y necessary w/ any `sed` between `/address/d` statements - `;` a semicolon will do.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought that if you were using *multiple* editing commands, `-e` was required. But different seds are different; this is for GNU sed. BSD sed doesn't support the `/I` modifier so I deduced he was using GNU.

Comment: If you use `-E` you do not need to escape `()|`.